# Online editor - execCommand and download questions

Tags: javascript, download, prompt, execcommand

I'm working on an online editor ,and I've got some of the basic functions(B,I,U and so on) but I can't understand how

richTextField.document.execCommand("InsertOrderedList",false,newUL);
and
richTextField.document.execCommand("InsertUnorderedList",false,newUL);
work.

Neither highlighting the text/simply clicking the button worked .

The other question is : is it possible to display the browser's "Save" window when clicking on a button?For exapmle ,the one when we save an image from the webpage.

Comment: https://github.com/rndme/download can download string content as a file, like `download(richTextField.document.outerHTML, "mypage.html", "text/html")`

Comment: I'd suggest removing the phrase "... I didn't have time to look for some examples".  That is likely to deter folks from trying to assist.

Comment: Well I've got to go to the hospital for a surgery I'm going to have plus tests ,homeworks and so on ,but well no problem ,thanks for the advice .@dandavis if I don't want to open another window ,the <download> script would be enough? Docx etc. are supported as well?